# Auto logoff while closing the winform

Tags: c#

I want to make auto logoff while closing the winform without timer access. How do I do that?

Comment: Anything you've tried so far, any particular places you're having trouble? If you expect us to put in effort into an answer, please put some effort into the question.

Comment: you can try `FormClosing` Event

Comment: I didn't try any code ..I surfed in net but many of them given using timer method ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand what do you mean by `without timer access` but you may run a process or a command while the form is closing using the `FormClosing` event.

If you would like to log off the user when the form is about to close, you may try to use the executable file `shutdown.exe` as a process and its argument `/l`

**Example**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing); //Link FormClosing event to Form1_FormClosing
}
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Process logoff = new Process(); //Initialize a new process
    ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(); //Initialize a new ProcessStartInfo
    ProcessInfo.FileName = "shutdown.exe"; //Set the FileName of ProcessInfo
    ProcessInfo.Arguments = "/l"; //Log off, see 'shutdown.exe /?' for more information
    //ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //Hide the process window (not required)
    logoff.StartInfo = ProcessInfo; //Associate ProcessInfo with logoff.StartInfo
    logoff.Start(); //Start the process
}
```

This will start the executable file `shutdown.exe` as a new process with its arguments `/l` which means log off the current user

**Notice that:** `FormClosing` is fired when the form is about to close. You may stop the form from closing by setting `e.Cancel` to `true`

<sup>**Example**</sup>

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true; //Don't close the form
}
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)